# Energy flux for Bose-Einstein particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises

> Consider a medium in which energy is carried by a class of Bose-Einstein particles (each of energy $\varepsilon = \hbar \omega$) with dispersion relation $\omega = Dk^2$, where $D$ is a constant, $\omega$ is the frequency, and $k$ is the wave-vector ($k = \sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2}$). Provide an integral expression for the one-sided energy flux in the positive $z$-direction within the material at equilibrium at temperature $T$. Assume that these particles have two polarizations and have known chemical potential $\mu(T)$.
>
> *Hint*: The speed of propagation of these particles can be calculated by $v = \partial \omega / \partial k$.

I am confused about what form of density of states and integration limits to use for this problem.